# Different Images for top and bottom of DIV's border

Tags: html, css

I have a site that I'm working on, and one of the requirements is that it cannot use any client side scripting (jQuery/JavaScript). And since I'm not *that* great with CSS, I'm a little stuck here.

I have a simple div, which should have a "border image". But I can't use the CSS `border-image` since it doesn't work with IE (already tested), and I can't get two different images for top and bottom to work with `background-image:` - so now I'm left wondering what I can do...

Below is what it should look like, both the arrow-looking things are 2 png files:

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this? By using just 1 div, and 2 images? Without JavaScript, and also maintaining cross-browser compatibility (with some exceptions, like ie6<)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in: IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari

**CODE:**

```
    <style>
      #Container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border:1px solid #000000;
      }


      .boxTop {
        position: relative;
        left: 100;
        top: 100;
        width: 200px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color:#00CC00;
        /*place background image css code here and remove line above*/
      }

      .box {
        position: relative;
        left: 100;
        top: 100;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color:#CC0000;
      }

      .boxBtm {
        position: relative;
        left: 100;
        top: 100;
        width: 200px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color:#0000CC;
        /*place background image css code here and remove line above*/
      }
    </style>

    <div id="Container">
        <div class="boxTop"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="boxBtm"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Darcey's solution is very good. The box div with 3 divs inside, the middle one for content and the other 2 for the images (with css property background-image).

If you don't want to modify your html you could try playing with css :before and :after
[Example](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html)

Comment: With just one div he should try the :before / :afer stuff, as I said, but I think the 3 divs approach is more browser-safe

Answer (score 0):

First solution: use just **`gradient`s**. No images, no extra elements or even pseudo-elements.

Of course, `gradient`s are not supported by IE9 and older, so another solution would be to use **multiple backgrounds**.

*IE8 and older don't support multiple backgrounds the CSS3 way*, but you could use `AlphaImageLoader` `filter` as fallback for these browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If the block has fixed `height` and `width` just set background one image and `padding`s. If it has fixed `width` use @Mr. Alien's solution. And if it has fixed `height` crop image horizontaly and make background `repeat-x`. If both `width` and `height` are dynamic i'd suggest to use 2-3 additional divs anyway (i know you want to avoid it), i dont think playing with `:before` and `:after` is better.